# test OpenAI‘s Spinup error ,No module named 'joblib'

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have installed Spinup but when I run the test command:

```
python3 -m spinup.run ppo --hid "[32,32]" --env Walker2d-v2 --exp_name mujocotest
```

> error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'

but I have already installed 'joblib' and import joblib in python3 with no error.

Comment: try uninstalling Spinup and reinstall it now that you've installed joblib